# How to customise Media controller in exoplayer

Tags: android, exoplayer

I'm searching for 2 days to find out how to change the media controller in exoplayer and all resources refer to this link http://www.brightec.co.uk/ideas/custom-android-media-controller. please correct me if I'm wrong but I think in this tutorial we can customize old media player in android not exoplayer.

Comment: as you can see in exoplayer demo player activity they are using mediacontroller instead of that you can make you own customize controller specified in that link

Answer (score 0):

Reference from: http://google.github.io/ExoPlayer/doc/reference/

> A PlaybackControlView can be customized by setting attributes (or calling corresponding methods), overriding the view's layout file or by specifying a custom view layout file, as outlined below.